# Host command reverse result

Tags: host, sh

For example I do in Linux using `host` command:

```
host yy.yyy.yy.y
```

Result:

```
Host z.zzz.zz.z.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Then I repeat `host` command in a reverse with `z.zzz.zz.z` than I got a result of past`yy.yyy.yy.y`:

```
Host z.zzz.zz.z
```

Result:

```
Host yy.yyy.yy.y.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

What is occured and why is that result?

When I try got a WHOIS address of z.zzz.zz.z and yy.yyy.yy.y I got for example:

```
  yy.yyy.yy.y --> KOREA NIC
  z.zzz.zz.z --> JAPAN NIC
```

A result via WHOIS is on properly address, but when I use `host` command it result same.

For others who not understand my question look at this:

```
xx@yy:$ host 61.206.19.1
Host 1.19.206.61.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
xx@yy:$ host 1.19.206.61
Host 61.206.19.1.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)  <--- Why 61.206.19.1 ? WHOIS don't respond this IP
```

Comment: Your question is utterly unclear. Use the real IP addresses in your question.

Comment: Are you on IP a.b.c.d and are you trying d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa?  (Note the reversed sequence in abcd and dcba)

Comment: I believe the OP has no idea at all what he/she's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't understand your question fully, but:

If you want to perform a reverse lookup e.g. of 1.2.3.4 using the `host` command you simply type

```
host 1.2.3.4
```

That's it. You don't need to use anything in-addr.arpa or invert the bytes when using the `host` command in order to perform a reverse lookup.

Comment: Look at question. I've edited.

Comment: Read my answer again. I believe it perfectly explains what you want to know. Maybe you should also read some docs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#IPv4_reverse_resolution

Comment: Sorry, it's reversed. I have bad day sorry! I know know. Solved.